# How to find rolling mean using means previously generated using R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rolling-computation

Hope the community can help me since I am relatively new to R and to the StackOverflow community.

I am trying to replace a missing value of a group with the average of the 3 previous years and then use this newly generated mean to continue generating the next period missing value in R either using dplyr or data.table. My data looks something like this (desired output column rounded to 2 digits):

```
df <- data.frame(gvkey = c(10443, 10443, 10443, 10443, 10443, 10443, 10443, 29206, 29206, 29206, 29206, 29206), fyear = c(2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), receivables = c(543, 595, 757, NA, NA, NA, NA, 147.469, 161.422, 154.019, NA, NA), desired_output = c(543, 595, 757, 631.67, 661.22, 683.30, 658.73, 147.47, 161.42, 154.02, 154.30, 156.58))
```

I have attempted the following line of code, but it does not use the newly generated number:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(mean_rect=rollapply(rect,3,mean,align='right',fill=NA))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your desired fill value depends on any previously created fill values, I think the only reasonable approach is a trusty `for` loop:

```
df$out <- NA

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (!is.na(df$receivables[i])) {
    df$out[i] <- df$receivables[i]
  } else {
    df$out[i] <- mean(df$out[(i-3):(i-1)], na.rm = T)
  }
}

   gvkey fyear receivables desired_output      out
1  10443  2005     543.000         543.00 543.0000
2  10443  2006     595.000         595.00 595.0000
3  10443  2007     757.000         757.00 757.0000
4  10443  2008          NA         631.67 631.6667
5  10443  2009          NA         661.22 661.2222
6  10443  2010          NA         683.30 683.2963
7  10443  2011          NA         658.73 658.7284
8  29206  2017     147.469         147.47 147.4690
9  29206  2018     161.422         161.42 161.4220
10 29206  2019     154.019         154.02 154.0190
11 29206  2020          NA         154.30 154.3033
12 29206  2021          NA         156.58 156.5814
```